# Add upload progress to Google Drive script using python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

This is my code:

```
media_body = MediaFileUpload(file_name , resumable=True)
body = {
    'title': file_name,
    'description': 'Uploaded By Bardulf'}
file = DRIVE.files().insert( body=body, media_body=media_body, fields='id, alternateLink').execute()
if file:
    print(file_name + " uploaded successfully")
prem = DRIVE.permissions().insert( fileId=file.get('id'), body={'type': 'anyone', 'value': 'anyone', 'role': 'reader', 'withLink': True}).execute()
print ("Your sharable link: "+ "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + file.get('id')+'/view')
```

I want add progress bar, so I use this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload), add change my code to:

```
media_body = MediaFileUpload(file_name , resumable=True)
body = {
    'title': file_name,
    'description': 'Uploaded By Bardulf'}
file = DRIVE.files().insert( body=body, media_body=media_body, fields='id, alternateLink').execute()
if file:
    print(file_name + " uploaded successfully")
prem = DRIVE.permissions().insert( fileId=file.get('id'), body={'type': 'anyone', 'value': 'anyone', 'role': 'reader', 'withLink': True})
response = None
while response is None:
  status, response = prem.next_chunk()
  if status:
    print ("Uploaded %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

print ("Your sharable link: "+ "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + file.get('id')+'/view')
```

When I run my script I get:

```
    status, response = prem.next_chunk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 899, in next_chunk
    if self.resumable.size() is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'
```

I use api v2 and python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to monitor the progress of uploading the file, not setting the permissions:

```
media_body = MediaFileUpload(file_name, resumable=True)
body = {
    'title': file_name,
    'description': 'Uploaded By Bardulf'}
file = DRIVE.files().insert( body=body, media_body=media_body, fields='id, alternateLink')

response = None
while response is None:
  status, response = file.next_chunk()
  if status:
    print ("Uploaded %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

if file:
    print(file_name + " uploaded successfully")
prem = DRIVE.permissions().insert( fileId=response.get('id'), body={'type': 'anyone', 'value': 'anyone', 'role': 'reader', 'withLink': True})

print ("Your sharable link: "+ "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + response.get('id')+'/view')
```

And you also need to remove that stray `execute()` when you are using resumable media.

Comment: When I try, I get `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'next_chunk'`

Comment: @Bardulf sorry my bad, you also need to remove the stray `.execute()` when you are using resumable media. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I change it, and I get error on `prem`  it show `AttributeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: @Bardulf edited again, the `response` is like the result of `.insert(...).execute()` so use that to get the ID. Third time's the charm?